# Can't add Azure Search to SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I have created Azure Search resource, and also SQL Database.

I'm trying to use "Add Azure Search" option in Azure Portal.

It splited to 2 steps.

1. Data source creation (done)
2. Indexer creation

When i'm trying to create indexer, it says

> Import configuration failed, error creating Index

> Error creating Index: "The request is invalid."

What does it mean? There is no any details.

My Table Schema looks like this:

[image: Table schema]

Comment: How are you trying to do this operation? Are you using the Portal? What does your table schema look like? Please edit your question and include some screenshots.

Comment: ok, info added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you change any of the types in the index from the defaults?  Here is a mapping of what SQL types map to Azure Cognitive Search index field types: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers#mapping-between-sql-and-azure-cognitive-search-data-types  From my link, nvarchar maps to Edm.String or Collection(Edm.String). In your screenshot above, it looks like you've changed several field types (to Edm.DateTimeOffset and Edm.Int64, for example). That may be causing the error when it tries to create the index.

Or, it may be that you specified a ‘suggester name’ and ‘search mode’, but none of the index fields have ‘Suggester’ checked (hard to tell if the screenshot includes all fields or not).  If you need a suggester, you should mark at least one field to use it.  If you don’t need it, don't fill in those fields; otherwise the index creation will fail.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, all selected columns are nvarchar.

Comment: From my link, nvarchar maps to Edm.String or Collection(Edm.String).  In your screenshot above, it looks like you've changed several field types (to Edm.DateTimeOffset and Edm.Int64, for example).  That may be causing the error when it tries to create the index.

Comment: thank you, the problem was in "suggester". I left field empty and index was created.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the solution!  We will also update the Azure portal to provide a better error message in this scenario.